# Como bloquear determinadas teclas num input usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Galera, tenho uma função em javascript onde permito apenas números, vírgula (,) e hífen (-) em um input.

O problema é que posso digitar quantas vírgulas (,) e hífens (-) que eu quiser. Queria saber como faço para permitir apenas uma virgula ou menos.

Meu javascript

```
// Somente numeros e , e -
function SomenteNumero(e) {
var tecla = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58 || tecla === 44 || tecla === 45 || tecla === 13))
    return true;
else {
    if (tecla === 8 || tecla === 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

Acho ele assim no input:

```
  <input type='text' name='mg' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'>
```

Comment: Qual o padrão que você está procurando? Moeda? Dois números separados por vírgula? Um número que permite frações? Explique com mais detalhes por favor.

Comment: O hífen será usado para identificar números negativos ou poderá existir no meio do número? Você deseja permitir números como `-10`, `10`, `10,11`, `-10,11`, `0`, `-0`, `0,123` e `-0,123`?

Comment: o hífen e apenas para números negativos, ou seja so pode ser usando no inicio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Devido ao fato de o AP precisar utilizar valores positivos ou
>   negativos, editei a resposta sugerindo o plugin `Mask money` ao invés do `jQuery Mask` - https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

## Mask money

Use o plugin [mask money](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney), é ainda mais fácil de usar do que o anterior.

### Opções de configuração

- `allowNegative`: permite valores negativos se setado para `true`
- `prefix`: adiciona um prefixo no input, ex.: `R$ 9,99`
- `suffix`: adiciona um "posfixo" no input, ex.: `9,99 $`
- `thousands`: define o separador de milhar, o separador padrão é `,`
- `decimal`: define o separador de decimais, padrão e `.`

### Opções de manipulação

- `.maskMoney('destroy')`: remove a máscara do elemento
- `.maskMoney('unmasked')`: retorna um valor `float` sem a máscara, ex.: ex.: `('R$ 1.234,56' => 1234.56)`

Ainda há outras opções de uso. Veja o exemplo aplicando a máscara para o seu caso.

```js
$("#myInput").maskMoney({
  allowNegative: true,
  decimal: ',',
  thousands: '.'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" />
```

## jQuery Mask

Esse plugin - [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) é bem fácil de usar e customizável. Veja aqui um exemplo de como pode usar.

```js
$('#myInput').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {
  reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

Comment: jQuery Mask e muito bom, pois posso trabalhar com várias máscaras, data, hora, dinheiro e etc...  Já o outro plugin que vc mandou so trabalha com dinheiro. Tem alguma forma de informar números negativos no jQuery Mask?

Comment: Não tem como. Antes de sugerir o outro plugin pesquisei no Google e encontrei algumas issues no GitHub do projeto e foi lá inclusive que sugeriram o uso desse plugin para formatar valores. Você pode utilizar os dois plugins sem problema algum, pois ambos são bem leves.

Comment: Entendi ok, só mais uma duvida com faço para usar o jQuery Mask e permitir apenas números em um input?

Comment: olha consegui fazer funcionar com o -, porém ele não formata de forma correta, da uma olhada. http://jsfiddle.net/6pco4om7/282/

Comment: Acho que não irá funcionar da forma esperada, não vejo porque não usar o maskmoney, que foi feito justamente pra esse tipo de formatação e ainda sugerido pela comunidade do jQuery Mask.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso através de uma expressão regular.

```
function somenteNumero(value) {
  if (/([0-9]+\,?)/.test(value)) return true;
}
```

Logo após o asterisco você tem a permissão da virgula. Com a expressão regular você monta a regra que for necessária.

Comment: Essa expressão regular aceitaria um texto ",,," (apenas vírgulas) e também "123,456,789" mais de uma vírgula.

Comment: Já editei a regex. Valeu. Agora só aceita uma virgula e números.

Comment: Ainda aceita mais de uma vírgula `/([0-9]+\,?)/gi.test('123,456,789')`

Comment: Criei uma outra supondo que é para valores monetários, mas ele também comentou sobre o hifen. Estou vendo como resolver isso com regex, mas acredito que não funcionará essa solução.

^([0-9]+\,?[0-9]+)$

Comment: Essa regex obriga que existam pelo menos dois números e, caso você utilize o modificador `g`, o problema de usar várias vírgulas estará presente novamente. Ele não sabe expressar o padrão que ele busca.

Comment: Tendo o padrão dá para resolver com regex. Removi o ´g´, vamos ver se tem a resposta do padrão que procura.