# Problemas com cálculos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom editei a pergunta, pois localizei o problema. Tenho um javascript responsável por fazer cálculos com os valores nos input, E tenho um plugin Jquery Mask ou MaskMoney para fazer a formatação do valor digitado.

Ambos os plugins apresentam o mesmo erro.

Jquery Mask - Quando digito 1,00 o javascript que faz o cálculo pego o valor 100.

MaskMoney - Quando digito algo, o javascript que faz o cálculo acha que o campo esta em branco.

Preciso de ajudar, des de ja agradeço

Segue o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".valor").on("input", function() {

    // Margem
    var valor = $(this).val();
    valor = valor.replace(".", "");
    valor = valor.replace(",", ".");

    // Custo
    var valorCusto = $("#custo").val();
    valorCusto = valorCusto.replace(".", "");
    valorCusto = valorCusto.replace(",", ".");


    var calculo = (parseFloat(valor) - parseFloat(valorCusto)) / parseFloat(valorCusto) * 100;
    var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");
    var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
    $("#" + inputMargem).val(resultadoMonetario);
  });

  $(".margem").on("input", function() {

    // Margem
    var valorMargem = $(this).val();
    valorMargem = valorMargem.replace(".", "");
    valorMargem = valorMargem.replace(",", ".");

    // Custo
    var valorCusto = $("#custo").val();
    valorCusto = valorCusto.replace(".", "");
    valorCusto = valorCusto.replace(",", ".");


    var calculo = (parseFloat(valorCusto) * parseFloat(valorMargem) / 100) + parseFloat(valorCusto);
    var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
    var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
    $("#" + inputValor).val(resultadoMonetario);
  });
});

$('.valores').mask('00.000.000,00', {
        reverse: true
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.js"></script>


Custo:
<input type='text' id='custo' class='custo valores' name='custo'>
<br>
<br> Valor:
<input type='text' id='valor1' class='valor valores' name='valor1' margem='margem1'> Margem:
<input type='text' id='margem1' class='margem valores' name='margem1' valor="valor1">

<br> Valor:
<input type='text' id='valor2' class='valor valores' name='valor2' margem='margem2'> Margem:
<input type='text' id='margem2' class='margem valores' name='margem2' valor="valor2">
```

o estranho e que aqui no stack ele funciona. 
Exemplo:

1º custo = 5,55
2º margem = 1,00
Resultado = 5,61

Já o mesmo código da problema na minha página e aqui:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/13/)

Comment: Hugo, não querendo ser chato com você, mas se você usasse o mask-money você não teria nenhum desses problemas que está encontrando. Como te disse em outra resposta, para se trabalhar com valores ele é muito mais que recomendado, inclusive pela comunidade do jQuery Mask. Desculpe a insistência, mas no meu ponto de vista, você está perdendo tempo com algo que não precisaria.

Comment: Essa conversão que você precisa fazer, o próprio plugin possui por default, como respondi na sua outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114596/como-bloquear-determinadas-teclas-num-input-usando-javascript/114604#114604)

Comment: Pedro tentei usar com o maskmoney e esta dando problema, olha so https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/12/  Percebi que com o maskMoney quando digito um valor e como se o input estivesse vazio, e para o mask e como se não tivesse as virgulas. O problema e esse

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/18/

Comment: Hum legal, porém o único problema e que precisa de sair do input para fazer o calculo, tem como mudar isso para o cálculo ser feito em tempo real?

Comment: Cara, já te dei uma resposta pronta, o que não é o objetivo do StackOverflow. Que tal procurar entender o que está fazendo? Da uma olhadinha nesse [link](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=o+que+s%C3%A3o+eventos+javascript). Desculpe a grosseria, mas um mínimo de esforço é válido, não acha?

Comment: sim concordo plenamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".valor").on("input", function () {
    // Margem
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var valorCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valor));

    var valorFloat = parseFloat(valorCorrigido) || 0.0;

    // Custo  
    var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
    var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
    var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0;

    // Calculo
    var calculo = (parseFloat(valorFloat) - parseFloat(valorCustoFloat)) / parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * 100;
    var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");

    $("#" + inputMargem).val(calculo.toFixed(2)).trigger('blur');
});
// Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
$(".margem").on("input", function () {
    // Margem
    var valorMargem = $(this).val();  
    var valorMargemCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valorMargem));
    var valorMargemFloat = parseFloat(valorMargemCorrigido) || 0.0; 

    // Custo
    var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
    var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
    var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0; 

    // Cálculo
    var calculo = (parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * parseFloat(valorMargemFloat) / 100) + parseFloat(valorCustoFloat);
    var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");

    var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).toString();
    resultadoMonetario = resultadoMonetario.replace(".", ",");

    $("#" + inputValor).val(resultadoMonetario).trigger('blur');
});

function removerPontos(valor){
    valor = valor.replace(".","");
    valor = valor.replace(",",".");
    return valor;           
}

function adicionarPontos(valor){
   if(valor.length == 1){
       return valor;
   }
   else{
   if(valor.length == 2){
       return valor;
   }
   else{
   valor = valor.replace(",","");
     var inteiro = valor.substring(0,valor.length - 2);

   console.log(inteiro);

   var decimal = valor.substr(2);

   console.log(inteiro + "." + decimal);
   return inteiro + "." + decimal;
   }
   }
}
});

$('input').mask('00.000.000,00', {
    reverse: true
});
```

Comment: deu errado, eu editei a pergunta explicando melhor o problema, olha se vc vai entender porque não sei se expliquei direito hahahah

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: ainda não deu certo hahahah, olha so:https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/14/

Comment: Faltou um detalhe que acertei

Comment: continua calculando errado olha so: https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/22/ O problema e que quando digito 1,00 o java acha que digitei 100. Muito estranho

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/30/

Comment: Amigo não tenho palavras para agradecer. Muito obrigado mesmo. Estou dando uma olhada aqui e vendo tudo o que vc alterou. A única coisa que percebi e que o . ainda da problema. Mas acho que ninguém vai usar 1.000,00 na margem ;)

Answer (score 2):

você precisa substituir os pontos e virgulas, segue um exemplo:

```js
// instancie o objeto intl apenas uma vez.
var intl = new Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});

var valor = {};
valor.text = "12.345.678,90";
valor.float = parseFloat(valor.text.replace(/[.]/gi, "").replace(",", "."));
valor.format = intl.format(valor.float)

console.log(intl, valor);
```

alteração no script:

```
$(function () {
    var intl = new Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
    });

    var parseFloatIntl = function (value) {
        value = value.replace(/[.]/g, "").replace(",", ".")
        value = parseFloat(value) || 0;
        return value;
    }

    var input = {};
    input.custo = $('#custo');
    input.valor = $('.valor');
    input.margem = $('.margem');
    input.inputs = $('input');      

    input.valor.on("input", function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var inputMargem = $("#" + self.attr("margem"));

        var valor = {};
        valor.Margem = parseFloatIntl(self.val());        
        valor.Custo = parseFloatIntl(input.custo.val()); 
        valor.Calculo = (valor.Margem - valor.Custo) / valor.Custo * 100;

        inputMargem.val(intl.format(valor.Calculo));
        inputMargem.trigger('blur');
    });

    input.margem.on("input", function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var inputValor = $("#" + self.attr("valor"));

        var valor = {};
        var valor.Margem = parseFloatIntl(self.val()); 
        var valor.Custo = parseFloatIntl(input.custo.val());        
        var valor.Calculo = (valor.Custo * valor.Margem / 100) + valor.Custo;        

        inputValor.val(intl.format(valor.Calculo))
        inputValor.trigger('blur');
    });

    input.inputs.mask('00.000.000,00', {
        reverse: true
    });
});
```

Comment: ok e depois como converto ele para ser escrito em 3.333,33? pelo que eu vi com isso ai eu vou converter ele para 3333.33.

Comment: @HugoBorges, se você deseja formatar o numero para o formato regional (no caso do Brasil, o separador de milhar é o `.` e o decimal à `,`), você deve usar o `Intl.NumberFormat(locale)`

Comment: entendo, olha editei minha pergunta, não estou dando conta de arrumar, tem como vc pegar e fazer a alteração no meu java, e postar como resposta?

Comment: fiz uma alteração, possivemente você terá de fazer alguns ajustes.

Comment: entendi, porém não esta dando certo, fiz algumas alterações mas não funcionou. Não sou muito bom com javascript hahahahah

Comment: @HugoBorges, tente debugar o seu codigo, o DevTools to Chrome/Opera é otimo para isto.

Comment: notei que o problema ocorre com a mascara, por algum motivo quando digito 1,00 e como se tivesse 100 no input. olha so https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/11/